# Need help at aligning text image and buttons

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am in need of help. I am currently developing my new webstore for my website, and I cannot figure out ho to properly align my text, images and buttons. I have tried many things in order to align them, but I cannot seem to figure out how to do it myself. I'll provide more info if needed. Thanks in advance!

Here is my [code](http://pastebin.com/2bAQvmpu) and below you can see the result:

[image: Not properly aligned]

Comment: I've put your code into a JSfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/qLfusemy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you just want to align all the items vertically, you can simply give the container a value of `text-align:center` while giving the containing block a `width`. So for the purpose of your code it would be something like this. Not that I've changed your markup as you were using inline styling.

The wrapper I've set as `display:flex` to help it align nicely. You can read about flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">

<section>
  <h2>MVP</h2>
  <img class="img-rounded" style="float: left;" title="" src="//dunb17ur4ymx4.cloudfront.net/packages/images/d04fbf5918208479df283e7fa0ad8f0fcc0d7acb.png"/>
<button>helpme</button>
</section>

<section>
 <h2>MVP</h2>
   <img class="img-rounded" style="float: center;" src="//dunb17ur4ymx4.cloudfront.net/packages/images/f6f9b85569cc52ddc9bf5e57b4fd28309093fdcc.png"/>
<button>helpme</button>
</section>

<section>
  <h2>MVP</h2>
 <img class="img-rounded" style="float: center;" src="//dunb17ur4ymx4.cloudfront.net/packages/images/f6f9b85569cc52ddc9bf5e57b4fd28309093fdcc.png"/>
<button>helpme</button>
</section><

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper section {
    text-align:center;
    justify-content:center;
    width:200px;
 }

 .wrapper {
   display:flex;
 }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qLfusemy/1/)

Comment: It's kind of working, but the buttons and the alignment of the entire thing is wierd. https://ibb.co/jaC4RF

Comment: Let me add another comment, to show you what it looked like before i wanted to change it: https://ibb.co/iPF8mF :)

Comment: If you want the columns to remain in the center, you can use `justify-content:center` on the `wrapper`

Comment: @Marius if you want the items to align vertically, you can use on the `wrapper`, `flex-direction:column`

Comment: Alright, it's working on centering everything, but the buttons are still really wierd ? https://ibb.co/jZKJmF

Comment: Is there some other CSS overriding the buttons? Do they have a width? It looks like they are getting clipped. Without your code I don't think I can help further.

Comment: Here is the entire code + the page: Page: fireflake.namelessmc.com/nettbutikk Code: http://pastebin.com/LaimeSg2